# JQuery Event for when user presses enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the simplest way to have a function called whenever the user hits enter after typing in a textbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to listen for the `keypress` event.  It's probably easiest to do this with `delegate`:

```
$(document.body).delegate('input:text', 'keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) { // if is enter
        e.preventDefault(); // don't submit form

        // do what you want here
    }
});
```

Comment: @lonesomeday - Is there a difference between keyCode and charCode?

Comment: @Jared Two typos -- it should have been [`e.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) and `35` rather than `13`. `which` is a jQuery-normalized version, so it will behave reliably cross-browser.

Comment: e.which? I've never heard of that one.

Comment: Yes, keyCode reports 13. Good to know about e.which. :)

Comment: @lonesome I believe non-character keys should be detected in the keydown event and character keys in the keypress event - if I remember correctly this is a best practice proposed by PPK.

Comment: @Jared Yes, the ENTER key will trigger keypress cross-browser. I mistakenly assumed that it's not a character key.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Why 35? e.which is still reporting 13 (FF4): http://jsfiddle.net/Uffs9/

Comment: @Sime - Sure, I did too at first.

Answer (score 5):

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

$('#text').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter was pressed.');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dNfC2/

Answer (score 2):

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="send"/>
```

jquery code

```
$("#txt").keydown(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){
alert("enter button pressed");
$("#btn").click();
}
});
```

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/Xamkp/5/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'return',function (){ /*do something*/ });
```

you will need a plugin:
[jquery.hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/downloads/list)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's rather simple to do in the form you asked:

```
$('#idOfTextBox').keyup(function(event){
     // enter key pressed
     if(event.keyCode=='13')yourFunction();
});
```

Take note this will still append the enter key to the box. You might wanna try `keydown` or `keypressed` if you don't want that.

Be sure to check [keyUp()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) for more detail.

Answer (score -2):

Put the `<input>` in a form, and write a handler for the form's `submit` event.

This way you're not explicitly looking for any particular key; you're just waiting for the form to be submitted normally. And in every mainstream browser, pressing enter while filling out a form will submit the form.

Note that you do **not** need to have a physical submit button on the screen if you don't want (in which case the enter key will likely be the only way to submit the form).

Comment: If a user hits enter in a textbox, it won't submit a form, it should create a newline.

Comment: The default action in a textarea when you hit enter is to append a newline not submit a form. `input` and `textarea` behave different when the enter key s pressed.

Comment: @lonesomeday - I didn't say there was anything wrong with using textareas, it's just the behavior of hitting the enter key is not to submit a form, but create a newline in the textarea. Therefore, I think the answer is flawed.

Comment: I said `<input>`, not `<textarea>`, since the original question didn't specify. "Textbox" could have been referring to either.